# Is it acceptable to re-render the children 3 times in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have 3 components connected in one parent one.

Pseudo example:

```
<div>
 <Parent />
 <ChildMetaData />
 <ChildData />
</div>
```

On click of `<Parent />` I use the following function that's passed as a prop:

```
handleParentClick(tid,sifUser) {
    this.setState({
        tid : tid , 
        sifUser : sifUser
    },
    () => {
        this.loadChildRequestsFromServer();
        this.loadUserDataFromServer();
    });
}
```

State changes.

**=> All 3 components re-render.**

When my `loadChildRequestsFromServer()` finishes it changes state of global variable

**=> All 3 components re-render.**

When my `loadUserDataFromServer()` finishes it changes state of global variable

**=> All 3 components re-render.**

As you can see , when I click on my parent my components re-render 3 times. ( I check that by running console.log in one of the render function of the component, like `<ChildData />`.)

Is this an acceptable behavior , or am I doing something wrong?

I should note that both of the "load from server" functions are AJAX calls. And since  `loadChildRequestsFromServer()` and `this.loadUserDataFromServer()` are chained together , maybe I shouldn't immediately update the state after the first function is over. But rather pass the data to the next function and update the it there.

Comment: The components in your pseudo example don´t have a parent-child relationship, they are just siblings.

Comment: They are child-parent/master-slave in database, that's why I named them that. I guess you can ignore the naming of components. It can confuse people. But it has semantic meaning for me.

Comment: You might consider adding an optional parameter that suppresses the re-render for when you know you'll be doing multiple triggering calls sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly fine for your components to re-render 3 times.
Because there are 3 distinct states of your parent:

1. without any ajax results
2. with ajax results from first call
3. with ajax results from both calls

React will filter out all unnecessary DOM-updates anyway, which is the main performance bottleneck.
You could filter out unnecessary updates by implementing `shouldComponentUpdate()`. This will also prevent unnecessary executing of `render()` function.

(update) If the first child only needs first ajax call results, and the second child only needs second call results, then you could also considering giving each child state, and call each function from within its respective child.
That way, each child updates independently, and you get less render calls.
Number of DOM updates will remain the same = minimal as compared to the original solution.

If you NEVER need the state with only results of one ajax call, then you can chain like you describe. But that would make any error handling much trickier.

Comment: Lets say loadChildRequestsFromServer() finishes first and changes my state. <ChildMetaData /> Is what takes that data and re-renders with it ,
 <ChildData /> won't render cause we still don't have any data needed for it to render. React wont touch  <ChildData /> since it would be an unnecessary update.Then loadUserDataFromServer() finishes. <ChildMetaData /> Doesn't depend on that data so the react wont touch it's DOM , but  <ChildData /> does, so it renders it.Now if I run console.log , it will only log calls to render function but DOM won't actually change 3 times.Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes. Added another thought to answer: you may consider putting each call in its respective component. That way, parent does not need to update 3x, and each child only updates 2x (initial + with ajax results).

Comment: Awesome ,got it! Which would you say is better? To have all ajax function in some parent scope or in each individual component? I still lack experience so it' hard to figure out which case is better. Initially I thought it would be good to have all my data fetching functions in a global scope so I can send data to child components from there.

Comment: Well, it sort of depends: if the 2 calls are really independent (so it does not matter eg which result comes in first), then putting them in children could be considered  better. But if your app grows, then it is good practice to try and keep state as high up in your component tree as possible, keeping as many children as possible pure (i.e. Stateless). In your case, I would keep them in the parent: the multiple renders are a low price to pay to keep your code clear and understandable, by keeping all logic in the parent.

Comment: Thank you , I'll keep them in parent. <ChildMetaData /> and  <ChildData /> are absolutely dependant on which <Parent /> element was clicked so it makes sense.